# requested feature is not enabled in this environment

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, okta, okta-api, account-linking

I'm trying to access the authorization server that i have in okta, so i can see the users profile (in this case the user first name and favorite color )from the alexa skill but keep getting an error.

i just want to retrieve the user info (claims in okta name/color).i already set up the account linking in alexa, so there is probably an easier approach since the clientID and clientSecret is already configured.

#### Error message

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "The requested feature is not enabled in this environment."
}
```

is this something i have to enable in okta? can i do it in okta developers console with the free tier?

#### Code

```js
function validateAccessToken(token, callback) {
    console.log("token: ", token);
    //start
    var clientId = '**okta open id connect client id generated earlier**';
    var clientSecret = '**okta open id connect client secret generated earlier**';
    var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer.from(clientId + ":" + clientSecret).toString("base64");
    var https = require('https');
    var tokenParam = '?token=' + token;
    var tokenHintParam = '&token_type_hint=access_token';
    var tokenQuery = tokenParam + tokenHintParam;
    var optionspost = {
        host: '**your okta org**.oktapreview.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/oauth2/**your authorization server id**/v1/introspect' + tokenQuery,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': auth,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };
    console.log(optionspost);
    var jsonResponseUser;

    var firstName;
    var favoriteColor;
    console.log("pre Req Post");
    var jsonObject;
    var reqPost = https.request(optionspost, function(res) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        // uncomment it for header details
        console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

        res.on('data', function(d) {
            console.info('POST result:\n');
            process.stdout.write(d);
            console.info('\n\nPOST completed');
            jsonResponseUser = JSON.parse(d);

            firstName = jsonResponseUser['FirstNameClaim'];
            favoriteColor = jsonResponseUser['FavoriteColorClaim'];
            let responseVoice = firstName + '\'s Favorite Color is ' + favoriteColor;
            console.log("responseVoice :" + responseVoice);
            callback(responseVoice);
        });
    });

    reqPost.end();
    reqPost.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });

}


const FavoriteColorHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
            request.intent.name === 'FavoriteColorIntent';

    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        let favoriteColor = '';
        let request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        console.log(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.accessToken);
        let token = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.accessToken;
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            validateAccessToken(token, function(result) {
                // setTimeout(1000000000000);
                console.log("inside Opp Handler, responseVoice: " + result);
                resolve(handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(result).getResponse());
            });
        });

    },
};
```

Comment: My guess is that you have a workforce account and not a developer account. Create a new (free) developer account at https://developer.okta.com/signup and you should be good to go.

Comment: Nop, i'm using the developer account.any other ideas? ....(i know im using the developer account because it says developer account)

Comment: Did you create the account on developer.okta.com? If so, does it have a `default` issuer under API > Authorization servers? If so, you should be able to use that and have everything work. If that doesn't work, please email developers@okta.com to create a support ticket.

Comment: yeap, it has a default server,but i created a custom authorization server, and thats the one that Alexa is linked to...should i only use the default server?

Comment: There's smart defaults for policies and such in the default server. You might have to change them to match in your custom server.